# modal does not work in semantic ui

Tags: jquery, laravel, semantic-ui

I want to use semantic ui it's modal.
I can't get it to work though, I included jQuery correctly and `semantic.js` but when my fn calls modal it does not show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('semantic/dist/semantic.min.js') }}"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('semantic/dist/semantic.min.css') }}">
<title>Laravel Quickstart - Intermediate</title>

<script>
    function fn() {
        $('.ui.modal')
                .modal()
        ;
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="ui modal">
<i class="close icon"></i>
<div class="header">
    Modal Title
</div>
<div class="image content">
    <div class="image">
        An image can appear on left or an icon
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        A description can appear on the right
    </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <div class="ui button">Cancel</div>
    <div class="ui button">OK</div>
</div>
</div>
<button onclick="fn()">sdfsdfsdfsdf</button>
<div class="ui bottom attached segment">
</div>
<div class="ui container">
@yield('content')
 </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

If I use Boostrap's js the modal works fine but why? I want to use semantic's not bootstrap's.

Answer (score 1):

include 'show' in your call

```
 $('.ui.modal').modal('show')
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** load your semantic CSS file before the JS, then via jQuery do:

```
$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
```

See snippet:

```js
$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">
    Modal Title
  </div>
  <div class="image content">
    <div class="image">
      An image can appear on left or an icon
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      A description can appear on the right
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui button">Cancel</div>
    <div class="ui button">OK</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="fn()">sdfsdfsdfsdf</button>
<div class="ui bottom attached segment">
</div>
<div class="ui container">
  @yield('content')
</div>
```